# Angular Deck Grid accessing cards in ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grid, scope

I am using angular deck grid (https://github.com/akoenig/angular-deckgrid)

to make a grid of ads and here what I am doing is -

```
div(deckgrid, class="deckgrid", source="ads" )
            .thumbnail.adGrid(style="word-wrap:break-word",class="a-card")
                img.img-thumbnail.margin-top-10(ng-src="/ads/thumbs/{{card.thumbUrl}}")
                .caption
                    p.control-label.text-center
                        i.fa.fa-eye.margin-right-10(tooltip="Views") &nbsp; {{card.views}}
                        span &nbsp;
                            i.fa.fa-user(tooltip="Bids Placed") &nbsp; {{card.bids}}
                        p Posted In:&nbsp;
                            span.badge ({{card.category}} , {{card.subCategory}})
                    h3 {{card.title}}
                        //span.badge.pull-right(style="background:#428bca") Available: {{ad.quantity}}
                    p {{card.description.substr(0,80)}}
                    p.pull-left(ng-if="mother.identity != card.uploader")
                        a.btn.btn-primary(ng-href="/browse/market/{{card.adId}}") Details
                    p.pull-right
                        a.btn.btn-primary(ng-href="/browse/market/{{card.adId}}") Details
```

But the problem here is the I am not able to get the value of card.uploader here inside the ng-if. how do i do that??

Answer (score 1):

Angular Deckgrid has a bug where `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` does not work. I'm not sure the plugin is still maintained unfortunately.

See https://github.com/akoenig/angular-deckgrid/issues/58